# How to truncate a number with two positions after the decimal point in python?

Tags: python, floating-point, string-formatting

I would like to truncate a number with only two positions after decimal point and return this number. But when I use the string format as `float(" % .2f" % number)`, it returns 1.0 when the given number is like 1.0000. How could I resolve this problem? Thanks a lot.

It seems like my description was not clear enough. Let me take the 1.0005 as an example. I would like to return the number 1.00 with only two positions after the decimal point, rather than a string "1.00". So I choose to use string format to truncate the original number 1.0005 to a string "1.00" which satisfies the requirement of decimal points but it is still a string, I would like to return a number. So I use the float to convert it to a float number, but it seems like `float()` in gonna truncate the number to 1.0.

Comment: Hi Prune, thanks for noticing. I have updated new description above.

Comment: Mathematically speaking, 1.0 is equal to 1.000. There's no "truncation" happening there: whether the value is represented as a string as `1` or `1.0` or `1.000` is entirely a matter of formatting, not of the value itself. More importantly, `float` objects use the IEEE 754 double-precision storage format internally, which does not provide any way of distinguishing numbers by representation, only by value.

Comment: Oops, I got it. Thanks for your help!